# has_many through association dependent destroy under condition of who called destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, destroy

Is there a way to check, within a `before_destroy` hook, what object (class) called `destroy`?

In the following example, when a `patient` is destroyed, so are their `appointments` (which is what I want); however I don't want to allow a `physician` to be destroyed if there are any `appointments` associated with that `physician`.

Again, is there a way to do such a check in the `before_destory` callback? If not, is there any other way to accomplish this "destruction check" based on the "direction" of the call (i.e. based on who called)?

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end


class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end


class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :physician

  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_anything_important

  private

  def ensure_not_referenced_by_anything_important
    unless patients.empty?
      errors.add(:base, 'This physician cannot be deleted because appointments exist.')
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just say:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end
```

Note the `dependent: :restrict_with_exception`. This will cause Active Record to refuse to destroy any Physician records that have associated Appointment records.

See [the API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and [the association basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent).

Comment: [`:restrict` was deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5ad79989ef0a015fd22cfed90b2e8a56881e6c36#diff-5870816b49b90e43340607bb11ed2514R91) Aug 10, 2012 in a branch destined for `Rails 4`. [The *association basics* guide was also updated](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a63fc94aa3689f1e781ac51411ec79a81c011d8a). `:restrict_with_exception` provides the same functionality as `:restrict` did; there is also another similar option, `:restrict_with_error`, that causes an error to be added to the owner if there is an associated object.

Answer (score 21):

Note that `dependent: :destroy` on a `has_many :through` relationship only deletes the association and **not** the associated record (i.e. *the join records will be deleted, but the associated records won't*). So if you delete a `patient` it will only delete the `appointment` and not the `physician`. Read the detailed explanation in [the API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

I have pasted the relevant paragraphs below.

**What gets deleted?**

There is a potential pitfall here: `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many :through` associations have records in join tables, as well as the associated records. So when we call one of these deletion methods, what exactly should be deleted?

The answer is that it is assumed that deletion on an association is about removing the link between the owner and the associated object(s), rather than necessarily the associated objects themselves. So with `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many :through`, the join records will be deleted, but the associated records won’t.

This makes sense if you think about it: if you were to call `post.tags.delete(Tag.find_by_name('food'))` you would want the `food` tag to be unlinked from the `post`, rather than for *the tag itself* to be removed from the database.

Comment: Great explanation, Thanks! I was having a hard time figuring out if dependent: :destroy deleted the association and the record on the other side.

Comment: This seems like a thorough answer, however, I have set it up as you said and when I try to delete a Patient (using rails admin), the Physician is removed also.