# Rails 4 dependant destroy through nested relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run a script to delete a whole bunch of students from our system, I am relying on the rails `dependent: :destroy` convention to make sure I clean up all data that's is related to those students.

I am pretty new to this system but this is how they structured the `has_many` relationships within the `student_application` model which belongs to a `student`.

**student.rb** *student model*

```
has_many :applications, class_name: "StudentApplication", dependent: :destroy
has_many :season_classes, through: :applications
has_many :payments, foreign_key: "student_id", dependent: :destroy
```

**student_application.rb** *student_application model*

```
belongs_to :student, touch: true
has_many :user_application_statuses, -> { order(id: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
has_many :user_application_tasks, through: :user_application_statuses
has_many :file_upload_tasks, through: :user_application_statuses, class_name: "Tasks::FileUploadTask", source: :user_application_tasks
has_many :payment_tasks, through: :user_application_statuses, class_name: "Tasks::PaymentTask", source: :user_application_tasks
has_many :payments, through: :payment_tasks
```

**user_application_status.rb** *user_applicaton_status model*

```
belongs_to :application_status

# Student links
belongs_to :student_application
has_one :student, through: :student_application
```

**payment.rb** *payment model*

```
belongs_to :student
has_one :payment_task, class_name: "Tasks::PaymentTask"
has_many :transactions
```

When I delete a user I am getting this error

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "student_applications" violates foreign key constraint "payments_student_application_id_fkey" on table "payments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(24747) is still referenced from table "payments".
: DELETE FROM "student_applications" WHERE "student_applications"."id" = $1
  (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "student_applications" violates foreign key constraint "payments_student_application_id_fkey" on table "payments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(24747) is still referenced from table "payments".
: DELETE FROM "student_applications" WHERE "student_applications"."id" = $1
```

At first I thought that there was an object at a deeper relationship level that was being left out. But as far as I can tell from looking at the tables and the source code there is no `payments_student_application_id_fkey` reference anywhere in the code, but i have found this in the `structure.sql` file

```
 --
 -- Name: payments_student_application_id_fkey; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: -
 --

 ALTER TABLE ONLY payments
     ADD CONSTRAINT payments_student_application_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (student_application_id) REFERENCES student_applications(id);
```

We are using Rails 4.1.14.1 and Ruby 2.1.6 and Postgres for the db. Any ideas as to what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you show the relationship setup in the user model?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or the cause?

Answer (score 2):

From What I can see...

```
# in pseudocodes
user has_one or has_many student_application dependent destroy
student_application belongs to a user
student_application has_many payments
```

Therefore deleting a user causes the associated student_application to get deleted as well... but the student_application's id is being referenced from the payments table, therefore causing the error.

Two ready solutions I can see:

1) Set a `dependent: :destroy` on the `student_application` model for `payments` ( or `payment_tasks` ) as well. This will ensure that the payments also gets deleted as well.

However, if you don't want this to be the case... then option 2:

2) Set a `dependent: :nullify` on the `student_application` model for `payments`. This will ensure that the ``student_application_id`column on the associated`payments`object to the deleted`student_application` is set to null, preventing the above error.

> `:dependent` Controls what happens to the associated objects when the associated parent is destroyed. More options for `dependent` [can be found here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).

Comment: Thanks bud, let me try that now, i never thought of trying nullify, i tried the first option but i think the payments model is being referenced by a few other dependants later on in the chain.

Comment: So I tried both options and it won't work either way, I have updated the story with all the relationships between the models.

Comment: do you need to destroy the associated `student_applications` on each user?

Comment: I also tried to `:nullify` the `student_appliciations` for the student, but that is updating the record and will bring the same error. I would preferably like to destroy all related data, because you could still get quite a bit of information about the user even though it's not referencing anyone anymore.

Comment: so... you will basically like to destroy a user, and destroy the associated student_applications, and destroy all associated payment... etc... ect... ?

Comment: Yeah there is a large cascade of data being deleted, pretty much anything that could have come from that user should be deleted just by removing him.

Comment: I am thinking of using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039880/has-many-through-association-dependent-destroy-under-condition-of-who-called-des something like that to stop the `student_application` from deleting the payments and then allow the student hook to do it later on